# How can I setup pandas module on Xcode?

Tags: python, pandas, xcode, macos

I can run Python code on Xcode, and I managed to install the pandas module using pip but if I try to import it I have this error:
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

Comment: What version of python are you running and what version of pip have you installed the module with? I have had problems in the past between conflicting python 2 and 3

Comment: Run `pip --version` and `python --version`, do Python versions match? You can also use `python -m pip install pandas` to ensure you are installing `pandas` for the right interpreter version.

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the latest version of xcode. Install Macports for your version of MacOS from, [Macports](https://www.macports.org/install.php). After installation of the pkg, update macports and confirm the system is working as expected. Open a terminal window and type, `sudo port selfupdate`, which should return, `MacPorts base is already the latest version`. Assuming you have python 3.7, type `sudo port install py37-pip` to install pip. To ensure pip for Python 3 is the default for the system, type: `sudo port select --set pip pip37`. Then install pandas, `sudo pip install -U scikit-learn`.